# ASP parameter is not passing to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Here is my ASP code

```
string studentid = dr["StudentId"].ToString();
        string studentname = dr["studentName"].ToString();
        Response.Write("<tr>");
        Response.Write("<td id = 'sid' >");
        Response.Write(studentid);
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>");
        Response.Write(studentname);
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write(String.Format("<td id = '{0}' onclick = 'update({0})' >", studentid));
        Response.Write("<img src = 'Edit-icon.png' height='20' width='20' >");
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write(String.Format("<td id = '{0}' onclick = 'deleteStudent({0})' >", studentid));
        Response.Write("<img src = 'ic_delete_48px-128.png' height='20' width='20'>");
        Response.Write("</td>");
        Response.Write("</tr>");
    }
```

whenever I'm clicking on td id="studentid" the JavaScript function is being called but the parameter is not passing.
Here is my JavaScript function:

```
function deleteStudent(x) {

        alert(x);
        var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "crudops.aspx?StudentId=" + x +"&operation=delete", false);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
        ...
```

Here alert(x) is saying [object HTMLCollection]
What's the problem? 
Help me out with suggestions.

Comment: it means `{0}` is not working and javascript is reading it as an object.

Comment: How to overcome that? @Roljhon

Comment: have you tried removing the single quotes?

Comment: Why all those `Response.Write()` calls? Create one string with `string.Format()` and response that: http://ideone.com/Mpdqv6

Comment: It's working in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yhx8pfL8/. Can you post how's that being sent to the client? is `studentId` a number?

Comment: `studentid` is a string @kblok

Comment: So if student is a string you should do: Response.Write(String.Format("<td id = '{0}' onclick = 'deleteStudent(\"{0}\")' >", studentid));